# Unable to get a rowindex from dynamically created Devexpress Grid

Tags: image, dynamic, grid, devexpress

I am trying to display a picture when clicking on a button in a DevExpress grid. The grid is created dynamically. It show the data in the grid fine but as soon as I try to get the value of the cell in which the image name is stored I get the following error:

> "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Below is what I have so far:

```
public GridControl CreateGrid(string[] ColNames, string[] FieldNames, string SqlData, params object[] pars) {
    grid = new GridControl();
    view = new GridView();

    grid.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    grid.ViewCollection.Add(view);
    grid.MainView = view;

    view.GridControl = grid;
    view.OptionsView.ShowGroupPanel = false;
    view.OptionsView.ShowAutoFilterRow = false;
    view.OptionsBehavior.Editable = true;
    view.OptionsBehavior.ReadOnly = true;
    view.OptionsSelection.MultiSelect = true;
    view.OptionsSelection.MultiSelect = true;

    for(int i = 0; i < ColNames.Length; i++) {
        GridColumn column = view.Columns.Add();
        column.Caption = ColNames[i];
        column.FieldName = FieldNames[i];
        column.Visible = true;
    }

    table = GlobalDBCTM.DataTableForSql(SqlData, pars);
    grid.DataSource = table;
    grid.BringToFront();
    grid.Tag = view;

    RepositoryItemButtonEdit btnPhoto = new RepositoryItemButtonEdit();
    btnPhoto.AutoHeight = false;
    btnPhoto.Buttons[0].Kind = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPredefines.Glyph;
    btnPhoto.Buttons[0].Image = Properties.Resources.copy;
    btnPhoto.TextEditStyle = TextEditStyles.HideTextEditor;
    btnPhoto.ButtonClick += new ButtonPressedEventHandler(btnPhoto_ButtonClick);
    view.Columns[8].ColumnEdit = btnPhoto;

    grids.Add(grid);

    return grid;
}
void btnPhoto_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var id = view.GetSelectedRows()[0];
    var photopath = (string)view.GetRowCellValue(id, view.Columns["PhotoPath"]);

    var path = Globals.PhotoRootPath + "\\" + photopath + ".jpg";
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason of the issue is in this line:

```
var id = view.GetSelectedRows()[0]; // issue when there are no selected rows
```

To avoid the IndexOutOfRangeException I suggest you use the following code:

```
string photoPath = (string)view.GetFocusedRowCellValue("PhotoPath");
```

Related help links:
  [Identifying Rows and Cards](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument642)
  [Obtaining and Setting Cell Values](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument753)
  [ColumnView.GetSelectedRows](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetSelectedRowstopic)
  [ColumnView.GetFocusedRowCellValue](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetFocusedRowCellValuetopic992)

Comment: Hi, tried your "(string)view.GetFocusedRowCellValue" suggestion but it did not work either. After some further investigation it seems that the last grid that is created gets the focus. I tried to put "grid.focus();" in a event handler to focus on the grid that was clicked but that seems to do nothing either.

Comment: @Wraith972 It is very strange... the (string)view.GetFocusedRowCellValue(fieldname) work perfectly to me. I'm using the code based on your snippet.